# method count(JobViewWrapper) is already defined

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, lazydatamodel

I'm currently learning spring boot and encounter an error message

```
method count(JobViewWrapper) is already defined
```

yes it's because it has 2 of the same method name , but the method has 2 separate function , the first one is to count all the job with deleted flag 1.
the second one (count-active), is to count all the job with deleted flag 1 and is active flag 1.

So i needed this 2 method, is there a workaround to do it?

```
@PostMapping(value = "/count")
public long count(@RequestBody(required = false) JobViewWrapper wrapper) {
    System.out.println("into controller count");
    if (wrapper == null) {
        wrapper = new JobViewWrapper();
    }
    System.out.println("Prepare to count service");
    return JobService.countLazyView();
}
    
@PostMapping(value = "/count-active")
public long count(@RequestBody(required = false) JobViewWrapper wrapper) {
    System.out.println("into controller count");
    if (wrapper == null) {
        wrapper = new JobViewWrapper();
    }
    System.out.println("Prepare to count service");
    return JobService.countLazyViewIsActive();
}
```

my service

```
public long countLazyView() {
    return lowonganKerjaRepo.countLazyView();
}
    
public long countLazyViewIsActive() {
    return lowonganKerjaRepo.countLazyViewIsActive();
}
```

Comment: Call the second one `countActive` instead?

Comment: you cannot have 2 methods with the same signature (name + arguments) in the same class. Rename one of them

Comment: Federico, i used 2 because i needed  the /count for counting all of them in repo it's only has filtering "where deleted=1"
and the method with value /count-active has query in repo "where deleted=1 and is_active=1"
So it would make the count difference record number

Comment: pedrohreis, JobViewWrapper is actually a class name, and i tried to rename the "wrapper" in that method, like "wrapper1" but still the same error
Any way to work around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to [overload method `count`](https://beginnersbook.com/2013/05/method-overloading/) you **must** select one of the three options available:

1. provide different number of parameters:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/count")
public long count(@RequestBody(required = false) JobViewWrapper wrapper) {
// ...
    return JobService.countLazyView();
}

@PostMapping(value = "/count-active")
public long count() {
    return JobService.countLazyViewIsActive();
}
```

2. provide different types of parameters:

```java
@PostMapping(value = "/count")
public long count(@RequestBody(required = false) JobViewWrapper wrapper) {
// ...
    return JobService.countLazyView();
}

@PostMapping(value = "/count-active")
public long count(@RequestBody(required = false) ActiveJobViewWrapper wrapper) {
    return JobService.countLazyViewIsActive();
}
```

3. provide different order of parameters (seems to be not applicable in this case).

If none of these options can be selectable, you'll have options:

1. Provide different names for these methods `count()` and `countActive`
2. Replace these methods with one method having additional parameter (API call may be changed to /count?active=true):

```java
@PostMapping(value = "/count")
public long count(
    @RequestParam(name = "active", required = false, defaultValue = "false") Boolean active, 
    @RequestBody(required = false) JobViewWrapper wrapper) {
// ...
    
    return active ? JobService.countLazyViewIsActive() : JobService.countLazyView();
}
```

Comment: So..yeah i used that number 2 solution because that will be the most easy and simplest way. I make a new class for that.
Thankyou Alex, you're a life saver..